# How do I access a <td>'s id in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How do I make a javascript function that alerts the id of a `<td>`? I tried:

```
function test() {
  alert(document.documentElement.id); 
}
```

But that did not work.

Basically, I am making a grid on the page using a table and when I mouse over each cell of the table I want the function to tell me the id of the cell. I already know how `onMouseOver` works and those details but I can't seem to make the function work.

Comment: using jQuery, `$('a').each(function () { alert('id: ' + $(this).attr('id')); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can put a single listener on the table:

```
<table onmouseover="showId(event);" ...>
```

Then in the function show the ID of any TD element whose mouseover bubbles up to the table:

```
function showId(evt) {
  var element = evt && (evt.target || evt.srcElement);

  if (element && element.tagName && element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td') {
    console.log(element.id);
  }
}
```

You can attach the listener dynamically, but you may need to deal with some minor browser quirks for older browsers. E.g. the following will work in any browser in use (the table has an ID to attach the listener, but there are other ways that don't require an ID):

```
<table id="t0">
  ...


window.onload = function() {
  var table = document.getElementById('t0');
  table.onmouseover = showId;
}

function showId(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var element = evt && (evt.target || evt.srcElement);

  if (element && element.tagName && element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td') {
    alert(element.id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
function test() {
    var idItem = document.getElementById('id'); 
    alert(idItem);
}

test();
```

This if you know the id but I did an example to show the id of each cell

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>td mouseover</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
        var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
        function showId(evt){
            alert(evt.target.id)

        }


        for(var i = 0; i < cells.length;i++){

            cells[i].addEventListener('mouseover',showId);
        }


    });


    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table>

            <tr>
                <td id="cell1">Something 1</td>
                <td id="cell2">Something 2</td>
                <td id="cell3">Something 3</td>

            </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's going to alert the *entire element* whose ID is set to "id". That doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: The problem is I don't know the id in advance. I kind of want the function to be a function of the id.

Comment: See the edited answer, I placed an example of how to do it without using Jquery. You can also use in each td tag the option onmouseover = "name_function (this);"

Comment: Thank you very much for the well thought out, helpful answer. I appreciate it very much!